# Why the subsystem of a SATA device is scsi?

Tags: storage, scsi, sata

By doing `udevadm info -a /dev/sda`

we can see something like:

```
  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:3d/0000:3d:02.0/0000:60:00.0/host6/port-6:0/end_device-6:0/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0':
    KERNELS=="6:0:0:0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
```

However, this device is a SATA SSD, why it's subsystem is `scsi`?

This line:

`KERNELS=="6:0:0:0"`
means SCSI address, correct?

In my understanding, they are different interfaces( SATA & SCSI ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface may be SATA or SAS or SCSI (or at least in part, ATA/IDE), but the protocol spoken on the interface is either scsi or a substantially similar superset (or in the case of IDE, subset) of SCSI or can be easily emulated by the SCSI protocol layer in the kernel.